# OWASP Command Injection Issue in ProcessStartInfo

Tags: c#, owasp

We have a method where we are getting OWASP threat,below is the sample code.

```
var process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "7za.cmd", 
                    Arguments = $"a -y -bd -bb2 -- {zipFileFullPath} {directory}\\*",                    
                }
            };
```

Here we are getting the issue as "Uncontrolled command line",could you please help to solve this issue.